# TFS Online CI build and Deploy to OnPremise IIS server

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, azure-devops

I am using TFS online Build process for settiing up CI and deploying.

I am having issues with the deployment. The build part runs smooth but the deployment part does not work at all. It does not give any error either.

I have tried variety of links/helps to configure my MSBuild Arguement but nothing has worked so far. Can any one help me here?

Here are the arguements I have used

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True;DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish;CreatePackageOnPublish=True;MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent;MsDeployServiceUrl=<<http://IP/Server name>>;DeployIisAppPath="WebsiteName";VisualStudioVersion=12.0;UserName=domain\userid;PublishProfile=PublishProfileName

/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=True /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=RemoteAgent /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=<<WebserverName>> /p:DeployIisAppPath="WebsiteName" /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0 /p:UserName=domain\userid

/p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PublishProfile=<<publish profile name>>
```

I am using VS2013 and the template I have tried are DefaultTemplate, GitContinuousDeployment templates.

Any pointers on this please?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you are using the old Xaml builds or the new vNext builds. In both cases its highly likely that the hosted build controller cannot access your server/IP address. This is probably not due to anything on your side and is because the hosted controller has limited connectivity to the outside world. 
Most likely you will need to setup a deployment agent: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/release/deploy-with-agents-vs

Comment: Thanks For your reply. I am using a local agent created in our environment I guess (Need to confirm with TFS admin). The agent name is TFS2-Local Build. If this agent is local agent as the name suggests, I can get the credentials it would be running and can go forward from there.

Comment: To answer another question: I am using Gittemplate.12.xaml as the default template. This is something available to me when I was creating the build agent.

Comment: I have another throught to you reply. Right now I am coping the build output to the same server as to where I am trying to publish.  Since build outputs are copied, I am thinking that the build agent is having access to the server.

Comment: What about the build log? Does that provide any useful information?

Comment: Hi,Build log strangely does not tell me anything. It does not seem to be picking up the publish step at all. Most recent completed activity seem to be the build. I have tried the latest way of creating build definition (non xaml) using VS online and I am able get it completed.

Comment: Great. I am glad I was able to help.